# How to add task to celery from another program?

Tags: python, redis, celery, daemon

We're using celery with redis as broker in a daemon-like program. How do we add a task from another program to this daemon? Is it possible at all?

EDIT:

In case the description wasn't clear enough, there are two separate programs with separate codes, and I'm looking for a solution other than importing tasks from the latter program.

Comment: @myildirim There are two seperate programs with seperate code, I can't import the file containing the tasks in the latter program.

Comment: For anyone wondering, if it is possible to initiate task remotely, the answer is - yes. This article describes the details: https://coderbook.com/@marcus/how-to-send-celery-messages-to-remote-worker

Answer (score 1):

Now it's possible.
Give a name to task in worker

```
@app.task(name='addTask')
```

Call from poducer by name

```
app.send_task('addTask', (i, 3))
```

[Example](https://medium.com/@tanchinhiong/separating-celery-application-and-worker-in-docker-containers-f70fedb1ba6d)

Answer (score 0):

> I'm looking for a solution other than importing tasks from the
>   latter program.

Bad luck for you. The celery docs mention that the worker and the client need to have the same software. Thus your client code needs to import a celery task and is responsible for calling it within application control flow.

References:

- [Celery User Guide: Tasks - How it works](https://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/userguide/tasks.html?highlight=challenge#how-it-works)